# Simulator is different to main storyboard and preview in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

As shown in the pictures attached, despite using constraints and stack views, the preview and simulator images are completely different. I have a feeling hat the problem lays within the view which I have placed in the content view but I don't see how everything can be so stretched off to the side?

Here is the GitHub link which shows my source code: https://github.com/Kones345/Social.ly

Any help will be greatly appreciated :) [image]

[image]

Comment: It appears you've uploaded the same image twice

Comment: @cjbatin I've fixed it now

Comment: Have you set the constraints for the table view as well? Looks like it could possibly be something to do with the view overflowing

Comment: Yeah I've tried using the table view both with and without clip to bounds and still no luck

Comment: I've downloaded it and having a play with it now. Looks like it could be your stack view layout though

Comment: Whoops - my bad... looking again...

Comment: Sorry this isn't much of an answer, however having had a bit of a play on it it appears that the Cell is overflowing. You can see it when you delete the constraints. This usually means that a constraint is missing somewhere but Xcode isn't telling you. Sometimes I find it easier to restart with a slightly different hierarchy solves it!

Comment: is your image set to scale to fit ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I believe I solved it. You're missing a couple of constraints on inside the PostCell. The FancyView you have on there needs both a height constraint and it's Aspect Ratio setting. This will keep the content within the cell. Another thing to do would be to remove the FancyView itself from within the content view and just use the cells content view and build your constraints around that, that will simplify things for you.

You may then need to change some of the other constraints or settings in your view to get your desired behaviour but this should certainly get you on the right track.

Comment: Should i assume this an Xcode bug? Because I've really deleted everything and started again using different techniques so many times now and still the same issues.

Comment: Did you try setting the aspect ratio and height on the Fancy view? That fixed it for me. I've had this issue before when i've put views within cells on a table view. It is annoying that xcode isn't telling you it's misplaced.